# PHP,SMARTY - File upload not working in IE alone

Tags: php, smarty

I have a form defined via smarty, consisting of multiple tabs for various purposes. Two of the tabs have file upload controls placed inside it. The form submission works without any flaws in Firefox, but when I do the same in IE8/7, form submission is working only for the first file upload control. The second file control is not at all picked up by the Browser, especially while submitting the form. The file upload control is defined in the normal way, and not making use of smarty tags to do that.

---

`<input type="file" name="e2c[vids_upload]" maxlength="100000"/>` this is the code. Working in Firefox without issues

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have 2 inputs with the same name.  Browsers expect unique names for each file input instance.  To see both with similar names, I'd suggest doing this:

```
<input type="file" name="e2c[vids_upload][]" maxlength="100000" />
```

This will essentially put each file into it's own index under e2c[vids_upload] so that you can see them both on the other side.

Admittedly, if this is the issue, I'm surprised that Firefox is working at all.

Comment: Thank you dear Matt, Your answer is too acceptable but to my case, the file name for the controls was unique, and the main issue which i finally found out was that there was a sub-form(one form nested inside another form) in the code, that was actually causing this issue. Strangely, it was working on Firefox, but IE did not accept it all. Finally I had to take the nested form out and create it separately, in order to make it work on IE. Thanks once again for your time and comments.